# Set terminal font size in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

How can I set the font size in the embedded terminal in the JetBrains PhpStorm IDE? The text is too small. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't have a copy here to test. Does `Ctrl`+`+` work?

Answer (score 95):

[LazyOne already pointed out where you can change this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436405/247893).

Keep in mind that you have to hit the "Save As..." button next to the colour scheme first in order to create a new colour theme - you  cannot change anything unless you create a *copy*.

PHPStorm protip - if you can't find the settings, just use the search field:

[image]

Comment: and the gotcha here:  For Webstorm 2016 after setting the font size you NEED to re-launch webstorm to see the applied fonts. So it often seems not to work until you reboot ws ....

Comment: WebStorm 2017 user here. You don't have to restart anymore to apply the changes.

Comment: @dschu Yep, but you still need to close terminal session for the changes to take effect.

Comment: so **console font** it is, thanks :) i always forget & search for terminal instead, thanks

Comment: @MuhammadAliAbedhence why I searched for "font size" :) Made it easier to find

Comment: It was moved to Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font (as of 2022.3)

Answer (score 61):

Another alternative is hitting CTRL/CMD+Shift+A and searching `console`:

[image]

After setting the font, rebooting is not necessary, just close then open a new terminal as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I still needed to restart phpstorm

Comment: I not need restart my phpStorm (on Linux)

Answer (score 18):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Console Font**

NOTE: that you cannot edit bundled color scheme -- you will have to make a copy of bundled in order to be able to make changes.

Comment: For me, I need to restart PHPStorm to see the change applied. Closing and then opening a new terminal doesn't work. Some have noted the latter works for WebStorm.