# Zoom console (terminal) font size using shortcuts

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I know it is possible to change the console font size under settings, however, that is very tedious. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436470/7123519)

**How do I change the console/terminal font size using shortcuts?**

Comment: There are dedicated actions for which you can assign custom shortcuts (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031685/783119) .. but they seem to affect editor font only. So for console it would be via Settings/Preferences only (be it directly or using one of the search functionality: "Help | Find Action..." or "Search Everywhere")

Comment: @LazyOne I know that ... I literally expressed that in my "question's" first sentence. Also, what is up with the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-116253](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116253) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Wow, how come they not have added such a basic feature yet? Well, this is just another reason for me to migrate to another IDE.